# Why do addresses get lowercased when stored in contracts?

Tags: solidity

I'm asking this, because I'm not sure if it's a bug or a normal behaviour. Here's a simple contract.

```
   pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
    contract Contract {
        address public someAddress;
        function storeAddress(address someAddress_){
            someAddress = someAddress_;
        }
    }
```

**Store** vs **Get**:

0x203D17B4a1725E001426b7Ab3193E6657b0dBcc6
0x203d17b4a1725e001426b7ab3193e6657b0dbcc6

If EVM understands only lowercased addresses then why do some services generate addresses that are mix-cased?

Comment: The question belongs to http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capitalization simply means the address has a checksum.Both will work well.
Refer to [Is Ethereum wallet address case sensitive?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2045/is-ethereum-wallet-address-case-sensitive) and [How can I check if an Ethereum address is valid?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/how-can-i-check-if-an-ethereum-address-is-valid) for details.